# What services would you recommend to ship belongings to graduate school beforehand?

Tags: university

I realize that this question is not exactly pertaining to academia but I couldn't think of anywhere else to ask this.  I fully expect to get several downvotes but please be kind and move my question if needed.

I will be attending Georgia Tech as a graduate student this fall.   Looking ahead at my summer schedule, I would like to ship my belongings  (several pieces of luggage as well as many boxes) to school ahead of  time and have them waiting for me when I get there.  Ideally, I'd like  the school to be able to hold my belongings for 1.5 months (~5-6 weeks)  before I arrive.  Perhaps it is unorthodox but that is the way that my  schedule will work out as I will be visiting some family before I move to Georgia.

I'd like to hear from you what your experiences have been like in  regards to shipping belongings to the school beforehand and if there are  any services that you can recommend.  I called the GATech post office  and housing office but both simply stated that they don't have any  storage space for student belongings and just said to ship my stuff a  day or two before I arrive.  This was obviously unhelpful to me so I  turn to the people here for any advice.

I also Googled around and was wondering if people had used any services like dormroommovers.com or Summer Storage | College Student Storage and Shipping | Collegeboxes.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You might be able to use [Travel SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com/) to get info on this.

Comment: Rather than trying to work through the housing office, I would try contacting the graduate coordinator for your department - whichever person is responsible for graduate student relations.  You could ask if they might be able to store your boxes in your assigned office.  Alternatively, they may be able to put you in touch with a fellow graduate student who would be willing to receive your boxes at their home and store them for you - especially if you offer to compensate them with money / beer / etc.

Comment: I initially thought this question was "boat programming" but on further reflection I think it's reasonable - grad students who are moving have different options available to them, compared to the general public.

Comment: I don't know about the shipping part, but I think your best bet for storage is probably a standard "storage unit" type of service

Comment: @NateEldredge (2 comments up) I can't argue with evidence, assuming you have some, but that seems like a very surprising statement to make.

Comment: @David: I'm not quite sure how you're counting; which of my comments do you find surprising, and why?

Comment: @NateEldredge zeldredge's comment is 1 comment up from mine; yours which says that grad students have different moving options available from the general public is 2 comments up, and that's the fact I found surprising, because I personally have never seen or heard anything that would suggest that to be true.

Comment: @DavidZ: for instance, as a grad student I would not be too surprised if another future grad student contacted me and asked me to store a couple boxes with personal belongings for a few weeks in my office. As a corporate drone, I *would* be surprised, and I would find this a bit unprofessional. (Incidentally, you can right-click on a comment's timestamp to get its URL, then link directly to a comment you want to reference.)

Comment: @StephanKolassa I _would_ have found that rather unprofessional as a grad student. If it's someone I know, that's different, but then I'm doing a favor for a friend, which has nothing to do with my status as a grad student or office worker or whatever. I don't think that makes the question academic-specific. (And I know about getting a comment's URL, but I find the "n comments up" style to be easier on the reader, and also to use fewer characters. Thanks for offering advice though.)

Comment: @David: I generally meant the fact   that there is a major university at the other end that has an interest in having the OP's move go smoothly, and is aware that as a student his/her resources may be limited. OP hasn't yet found a person there who's willing to help, but as in my other comment, I think there's a good chance that someone else will be.

Comment: Thanks for your help everybody.  So other than contacting the department directly, does anyone have experience with services like dormroommovers or collegeboxes?

Comment: This could be on-topic at [Expatriates.SE].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I moved coast-to-coast for graduate school, I used

1. UPS for my personal belongings (e.g., clothes, beddings...etc)
2. USPS Media Mail for my books and CD's
3. Southwest Airlines free check-in bags (they allowed up to three pieces back then)

PS: I didn't have any furniture to ship.

If there's stuff you won't need for grad school, send them home until you settle down somewhere with a permanent residence. It'll be cumbersome and costly to haul them around the country.

As for storage, I contacted the department secretary and asked if they could store a few boxes for me (and they kindly agreed). You may also write to fellow grad students in your department and ask if they could receive your boxes for you and store them in their office.

Hope this helps!